# Обновлять CHART Morris каждые 10 секунд

Tags: php, javascript, json, morris.js

Ребята, очень нужна помощь, в этом деле совсем новичок(
У меня есть график которому я задаю цифры с **phpmyadmin**,  но нужно постоянно нажимать *F5*. Какой скрипт сюда вставить, чтобы оно обновлялось само + по возможности, выводило рандомные числа в графике если отключиться, например, от базы данных (чтобы видно было, что есть динамика и на графике что-то меняется )

**БАЗА ДАННЫХ:**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "a-1800", "testing");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM account";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $chart_data = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $chart_data .= "{ year:'".$row["year"]."', 
         years:'".$row["years"]."',
         profit:".$row["profit"].", purchase:".$row["purchase"].", 
         sales:".$row["sales"].",
         sale:".$row["sale"]."}, ";
     }
     $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
```

**ГРАФИК:**

```
Morris.Bar({
 element : 'chart1',
 data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],  
 xkey:'year',
 ykeys:['profit', 'purchase', 'sale' , 'sales'],
 labels:['1 участок', '2 участок', '3 участок', '4 участок'],
 hideHover:'auto',
 behaveLikeLine: true,
 resize:true,
  gridTextColor: ['black'],
  gridTextSize: ['15'],    
  barColors: ['#ff6d6d', '#3333ff','#6d6d93','#0e0e31'], 

});
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать ajax

Comment: Та я знаю что нужно использовать ))) второй вопрос как , по этому и написал чтоб помогли

Comment: Так вы начните с чего-нибудь ) а вас уже направят )